# Knowing if there's an equivalent Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

Is it always possible to know if there's an equivalent Turing machine to a given machine such that it'll have a smaller number of states? (1-tape machine, minimizing it)

My intuition says that finding such machine in the general case is not possible, but what about just knowing if there's a simpler machine?

Is my question like asking "How to know if there's a simpler solution to a given problem"?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the number of symbols in the alphabet, then there are constructions of universal Turing machines that only use  $2$ [states](https://www.ini.uzh.ch/%7Etneary/tneary_Thesis.pdf).*
This means that every Turing machine with at least $3$ states admits an equivalent Turing machine with less states.

Turing machines with just two states don't admit smaller equivalent machines, unless their language is trivial.
This is because the standard definition of Turing machine restricted to have a single state would force the machine to either always accept or to always reject, so the machine can only decide trivial languages (but see *, which could allow the machine to run forever).

If you alter the definition slightly, then you can obtain single-state Turing machines that are a bit more powerful. See [this](https://www.nearly42.org/vdisk/cstheory/plain_power-one-state.pdf) paper for details.

---

*The precise definition allows transition from halting states. The machine stops when it is in a halting state and no transition is defined for the current symbol-state pair. Additionally, an infinitely repeated word on the otherwise blank portions of the tape is allowed. See the paper for details.

Comment: "Turing machines with just two states can't really be minimized, unless the problem is trivial.": actually, it is undecidable, since $\{\langle M\rangle \mid L(M) = \Sigma^*\}$ is undecidable.

Comment: @Nathaniel, yup! What I was trying to say is that there *exist* equivalent smaller Turing machines when the language happens to be trivial. When we consider the computational problem of *finding* smaller machines then, as you point out, we can't even decide if the language is indeed trivial.